# Свернуть неактивные пункты меню

Tags: jquery, меню, html

Всем привет есть меню на сайте http://cash-back.kz/.
Если открыть одно меню то оно открывается классно, если открыть второе или третье то тоже открывается, но не закрывается не активное меню.
 Например если открыть apple, а потом компьютерная техника, то пункт apple все так же будет активен.
Выкладываю Html и jquery меню
HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><span>Apple</span>
<ul>
<ul id="menu">
    <li><span>Apple</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span>Iphone</span></li>
            <li><span>Ipad</span></li>
        </ul>  
    </li>
    <li><span>Компьютерная техника</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span>Ноутбуки</span></li>
            <li><span>Компьютеры</span></li>
        </ul> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

JQuery

```
$('#menu ul').hide();
 $('#menu li span').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
    $(this).toggleClass("click");
    });
```

Класс "click" изменяет расположение стрелки.

Помогите плизз!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var nav = $('#menu'),
    ul = $('ul', nav).hide(),
    activeItem;
 $('li span', nav).click(function() {
     activeItem = $(this).next('ul');
     ul.not(activeItem).slideUp();     
     activeItem.slideToggle();
     $(this).toggleClass("click");
 });
```

Comment: работает но неккоректно, стрелочки сбиваются, которые показывают открыто меню или нет. Я оставил на сайте cashback.kz можете проверить!

Comment: @duddeniska, я думал, что со стрелочками уже сами сможете разобраться. 


    var nav = $('#menu'),
    ul = $('ul', nav).hide(),
    activeItem;
    $('li span', nav).click(function() {
        activeItem = $(this).next('ul');
        ul.not(activeItem).slideUp();     
        activeItem.slideToggle();
        $('li span', nav).not(this).removeClass('click');
        $(this).toggleClass("click");
    });

Comment: P.S. Кстати, только сейчас обратил внимание. Я же надеюсь, что у вас всего один элемент с id="menu"?

Comment: да, блин ну вот почти все идеально. Теперь работает но когда нажимаю обратно на эту же ссылку то стрелочка не встает на место((((( на сайте оставил без иземенений!

Comment: @duddeniska, [смотрите пример][1]. Вместо стрелочек, я просто подсвечиваю текст. Как видите, при повторном нажатии, цвет возвращается. Значит, и стрелочки должны принимать исходное положение 

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/skbnc/

Comment: ох и замучил я вас. СПАСИБО ВСЕ РАБОТАЕТ БЛАГОДАРЯ ВАМ!!!